# use data value as name to execute a matching function

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I use jquery `.data()` to get html data and split it as function name,but the name is a string, not a function, I want use the string name execute the matching function.

In this demo, I get the string name is **scale and scaleY**, how use the name execute scale and scaleY function?
Thanks a lot!

**the error like this:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < useData.length; i++) {
  var funName = useData[i],
  var excFun = new Function(funName);
  excFun();
  console.log(useData[i]);                      
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<section class="boxed">
  <div class="tweenItems">
    <h3 data-tween="scale scaleY"> test scale</h3>
    <h3 data-tween="scale scaleY"> test scale</h3>
    <h3 data-tween="scale scaleY"> test scale</h3>
    <h3 data-tween="scale scaleY"> test scale</h3>
    <h3 data-tween="scale scaleY"> test scale</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

```js
var scale = function(dir) {
  TweenMax.set(tweenItem, {opacity:1});
  TweenMax.staggerFrom(tweenItem, 0.8, {
    "opacity":1,
    scale:0 * dir,
    delay:0.8
  }, 0.1);
}

var scaleY = function(dir) {
  TweenMax.set(tweenItem, {opacity:1});
  TweenMax.staggerFrom(tweenItem, 0.8, {
    "opacity":1,
    scaleY:0 * dir,
    delay:0.8
  }, 0.1);
}

var tweenData = tweenItem.data("tween");     

var useData = tweenData.split(" ");
console.log(useData.length);


for (var i = 0; i < useData.length; i++) {


  var funName = useData[i],
  var excFun = new Function(funName);
  excFun();

  console.log(useData[i]);      
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Where is the error?

Comment: the error like this:

for (var i = 0; i < useData.length; i++) {
  var funName = useData[i],
  var excFun = new Function(funName);
  excFun();
  console.log(useData[i]);                      
}

Comment: I get the data vaule scale and scaleY can not execute match funciong

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? seems like there could be an easier solution to what you are trying to do but since your intentions are unclear from your code above, it is difficult, at least for me, to propose a solution.

Comment: There is just a syntax error in you snippet. `var funName = useData[i],
  var excFun = new Function(funName);` is supposed to be either `var funName = useData[i], excFun = new Function(funName);` or `var funName = useData[i];
  var excFun = new Function(funName);`

Answer (score 0):

yes i fix the one error

```
for (var i = 0; i < useData.length; i++) {
var funName = useData[i]; 
var excFun = new Function(funName);
excFun();
}
```

**But console give me this:**

**Uncaught ReferenceError: scale is not defined**
**why scale is not defined and how fix my code**
**thanks ++**

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind: Function hoisting, and eval().

Scale may be undefined due to function hoisting (scale is defined as a variable at runtime rather than a function which is executed in parse-time, which is prior to run-time).  If this is the issue, you can fix this this by redefining your functions.

Example:

```
var scale = function(dir) { ... }
```

becomes

```
function scale(dir) { ... }
```

The other thing I found odd was that you're using the Function constructor to create a reference to the function by string (of the name of the function).  I would suggest trying eval, perhaps wrapped in a try-catch for safety.

Example:

Instead of

```
var excFun = new Function(funName);
```

try

```
eval(funName + '()');
```

You can get rid of the whole for loop:

```
useData.forEach(function(fnName) { eval(fnName + '()'); });
```

Comment: but in the for loop eval only execute once

Comment: You may have an issue with the global variable tweenItem.  There is missing context on that variable, so I am unable to help with that.

Comment: Since I was able to fix your issue, would you consider this as the solution?